# Run time Exception in MIPS Assembly code

Tags: mips

Recently, I am learning MIPS. Professor give us an example of his code, asking us to find out the value. My problem is that after I type in his code, the run time exception comes out at " lw $t1, 0($s0) ".

line 8: Runtime exception at 0x0040001c: address out of range 0x00000000

Can someone helps me?

```
addi $t7, $zero,0x10010000

lw $t0, 20($t7)
srl $t0, $t0, 16
andi $t0, $t0, 0x00000FF

andi $s0, $t7, 16
lw $t1, 0($s0)
andi $t1, $t1, 0x0000FF00
srl $t1, $t1, 8

addi $s0, $s0, -8
lw $t2, 0($s0)
sll $t2, $t2, 24
srl $t2, $t2, 24

addi $s0, $zero, 1
sll $s0, $s0, 4
lw $t3, 0($t7)
srlv $t3, $t3, $s0
andi $t3, $t3, 255

addi $s0, $zero, 1
sll $s0, $s0, 2
add $s0, $s0, $t7
lw $t4, 0($s0)
andi $t4, $t4, 0x00FF0000
srl $t4, $t4, 16
```

Comment: `andi $s0, $t7, 16` You do realize that this will clear all bits except for bit 4? Why would you attempt to use such a value as an address?

Comment: I copy the code from my professor, he asks us to run this assembly code and try to find the value of $t0 to $t4. Does he mistype his code?